# in the formula of the conditional probability, what would happen if the conditioning event be a null event?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

In the formula of the conditional probability,

p(a|b)=p(ab)/p(b)

what would happen if the conditioning event be a null event, i.e. p(b)=0 in the formula?

thanks.

Comment: I am afraid this has nothing to do with programming, and as such is off-topic for this site. (Stack Overflow is not a general Q+A site.) There are, however, sister sites where this question might be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-existent event happens with absolute certainty, so its probability is 100%, thus

```
P(a|b) = P(a) / 1 = P(a)
```

P(a|b) in this case obviously means that there is no condition at all. As a side note, you can see all three are the same in this situation:

```
P(a|b) = P(ab) = P(a)
```